# undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass - Trying to edit a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have made a chair selling website, at the moment i want to edit a chair post, no matter who posted it.
however its coming up with an error 'undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass'.
Not sure why. Ive tried with only @chair in the edit form.
I have added some more code from models and the terminal below.

```
Started GET "/chairs/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-27 20:30:53 +0000
Processing by ChairsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /Users/benherring/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  Rendering chairs/edit.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered chairs/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (3.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 22ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <%= simple_form_for @chair do |f| %>
    2: <%= f.input :name %>
    3: <%= f.input :description %>
    4: <%= f.submit :submit %>

app/views/chairs/edit.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_chairs_edit_html_erb___2826282127562707280_70360397910180' .
```

```
class Chair < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end



class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
         has_many :chairs
end
```

```
class ChairsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @chairs = Chair.all
  end

  def show
    @chair = Chair.find(params[:id])
    @user = @chair.user
  end

  def new
    @chair = Chair.new
    @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @chair = Chair.new(chair_params)
    @chair.user = @user
    if @chair.save
      redirect_to chairs_path
    end

    def edit
      @chair = Chair.find(params[:id])
      @user = current_user
    end

    def update

    @chair = Chair.find(params[:id])
    @chair.update(chair_params)
    redirect_to chairs_path
    end

    def delete
    end

  end


  private

  def chair_params
    params.require(:chair).permit(:name, :description)
  end
end
```

```
<%= simple_form_for [@user, @chair] do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.submit :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried `<%= simple_form_for  @chairdo |f| %>`? Could you paste the full stacktrace?

Comment: Also post your models code. Documentation about nested simple from [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Nested-Models)

Comment: Just don't understand why you are passing a user in form.   If you need a form for a chair - `<%= simple_form_for @chair do |f| %>`

Comment: i have tried with only @chair and it does not work. ive added other code above

Comment: Also, so should i only need `@user` and `@chair` in the form if im making a new chair post? and only `@chair` if im editing a post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably pass `nil` to `simple_form_for`. I don't know how it happens, let me just describe some strange things I've found out:

You have incorrect nesting of methods in the controller - `#edit`, `#update` and `#delete` are nested in `create`. Either you did a mistake when you were copying it, or you have a piece of really weird code.

Logs show that user is fetched from the db, but there is nothing about a chair. That may be the reason for this behaiour - `@chair` is not initialized.

I would do two things to push debugging forward:

- check nesting of methods.
- ensure that `ChairsController` is not defined twice
- check if `@chair` is not nil in `@edit` (e.g. by printing `@chair.id` to logs).